# IntelliJ IDEA unused code detection

Tags: intellij-idea, grails-2.2

IntelliJ IDEA can find all the code that is unused, but it wont grey out all of it. I want it to fully analyze and gray out all properties in messages.properties file, but it does not do that. How can I force it to do so?

It would be also good if I could configure it to find the controller names from config.

Comment: Does [Unused Property](http://i.imgur.com/NMDroiy.png) inspection work for you? If not, please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Unused property works partially. That example is difficult to get... my file is 2000 lines of propertyes. And as i read it basically if it takes too long to get it will just skip it.